# Django inline formset, once all inlines full, the form creates an extra entry and saves it to the db

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Here is my code,

views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, View, UpdateView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

PurchaserChoiceFormset = inlineformset_factory(Worksheet, PurchaserChoice, form=PurchaserChoiceForm, can_delete=False,extra=5, max_num=5)

from models import Worksheet 
from forms import PurchaserChoiceFormset

class WorksheetStep1View(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'worksheets/step1.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):  # Exec 1st

        context = super(WorksheetStep1View, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['worksheet'] = Worksheet.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('worksheet_id'))

        context['choice_formset'] = PurchaserChoiceFormset(self.request.POST or None, instance=context['worksheet'])

        return context


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data()

        if context['choice_formset'].is_valid():
            context['choice_formset'].instance = context['worksheet']
            context['choice_formset'].save()

        return super(WorksheetStep1View, self).render_to_response(context)
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Worksheet(models.Model):
    completed_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True) 

class PurchaserChoice(models.Model):  # Choice made by the purchaser for model/floor

    model = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    floor = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)  # coming from API
    worksheet = models.ForeignKey('worksheets.Worksheet')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "PurchaseChoiceID {0}, WorksheetID {1} - Model: {2} - Floor: {3}".format(self.id, self.worksheet.id,
                                                                                        self.model, self.floor, )

    class Meta:
        #ordering = ('-model', 'floor')
        ordering = ('-id', )
```

I want only up to 5 instances of the purchase choice to exist, but after the form is full and saved again, a new entry is created. If i get rid of context['choice_formset'].instance = context['worksheet'] , it is even worse, it creates a new entry for every instance in the formset.

Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening? I also looked at UpdateView but seems like its got more things to it than I need and I don't think its the cause to my problem. I am not sure why its creating new entries instead of updating once the form has 5 entries in it and saved again.

One way I avoid this problem is just to delete all the choices on save each time, like so:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = self.get_context_data()
    if context['choice_formset'].is_valid():
        PurchaserChoice.objects.filter(worksheet=context['worksheet']).delete()
        #context['choice_formset'].instance = context['worksheet']
        context['choice_formset'].save()

    return super(WorksheetStep1View, self).render_to_response(context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I found wrong was that I was returning the wrong render_to_response (of the parent class with the context) which caused me to create new objects every time because the instance was lost.  This is what fixed it:

```
return self.render_to_response(context)
```

instead of:

```
return super(WorksheetStep1View, self).render_to_response(context)
```

And this also did not work:

```
return TemplateResponse(request, self.template_name, context)
```

I'll see if I can get a better idea of why TemplateResponse did not work.